# how to use pgrep to find a shell script process

Tags: linux, terminal, pgrep

I want to use `pgrep` command to terminate the running process in centos terminal. I tried:

```
pgrep fedora-proxy-k8s-postgresql | xargs -r kill -9
```

and I could not found the process because it's a bash script running in background:

```
➜  pydolphin git:(tencent-cloud) ps aux|grep k8s-pos
root     14131  0.0  0.0 113288  1084 ?        SN   01:35   0:00 bash ./fedora-proxy-k8s-postgresql.sh
```

What should I do to find and terminate the process using `pgrep`? Or I have to use `ps` command?

Comment: I think that the problem is that `fedora-proxy-k8s-postgresql` is more than 16 characters long, which is the limit for a name of a process. Check the actual name of the process (not the command line) by running `ps -o comm -p <pid>` on the pid of a running instance of the script. I assume you'll see something such as `fedora-proxy-k8s` which is the actual process name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```bsh
pgrep -af 'fedora-proxy-k8s-postgresql'
```

The pattern is matched against the  full command line when `-f` is set.

And if you need to kill the process:

```bsh
pkill -9 -f 'fedora-proxy-k8s-postgresql'
```

As mentioned in the comment by @aviro, `pkill` should be used carefully, in case some other processes running commands line like `vi fedora-proxy-k8s-postgresql.sh` exist, they also match this `pkill` pattern and will be killed. So you had better to ensure the process you want to kill is the only one whose command line matching the pattern, or write a more accurate pattern like `-f 'bash ./fedora-proxy-k8s-postgresql.sh'`, before you execute `pkill`.

For more details refer to the manpage of `pgrep`.

Comment: Of course if you have other processes running `vi` or `less` on the script, for instance, they would also be killed, so you should think of an improvement, or mention this caveat in your answer.